# Read only disk then disk gone missing after reboot

Tags: hard-drive, disk, partitioning, fdisk

I have a 3TB HD on /dev/sdb mounted as /media/work where I put all the heavy stuff from work. (I dont know if I've put the info correctly, I'm new to Linux)

Today I tried to edit a file then noticed that it was 'read-only'. I checked disk utility if there was any issue with the HD and everything seemed fine. I rebooted just in case and then from now on I cant access the partition.

df -l displays:

```
Filesystem            Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/mapper/vg_lcm01-lv_root
                       50G   14G   33G  30% /
tmpfs                 3.8G   52M  3.8G   2% /dev/shm
/dev/sda1             477M  165M  288M  37% /boot
/dev/mapper/vg_lcm01-lv_home
                      858G  700G  115G  86% /home
```

blkid displays:

```
/dev/mapper/vg_lcm01-lv_root: UUID="b0665a45-6fe1-4aa0-b8a0-cc4a57bddac1"    TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda1: UUID="675192c1-5d3c-4d05-8985-962d3482edf6" TYPE="ext4" 
/dev/sda2: UUID="dF78PK-rmmO-SeXm-XyU6-eWL8-afxm-bRP8r4" TYPE="LVM2_member" 
/dev/mapper/vg_lcm01-lv_swap: UUID="eb07f26d-f48c-4c4b-8994-b77bbd768cc9" TYPE="swap" 
/dev/mapper/vg_lcm01-lv_home: UUID="a574ae1c-4de5-48ce-b6e8-9353dff06911" TYPE="ext4"
```

Does anyone has any idea of what happened and what can I do to repair the disk and/or retrieve the files?

Comment: No `/dev/sdb`? How do you connect/mount the disk? Dynamically (plug&play USB) or is it a static SATA disk?

Comment: It is a SATA disk. I plugged the cables and then followed instructions on the internet in order to mount it. It has been working just fine for months

Comment: Maybe time to check/re-seat the connector then.  A marginal connector can cause errors that make Linux remount the disk R/O to avoid corrupting the file system. Later the connector goes off and the disk doesn't show when you reboot. Assuming you are lucky ...

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Can I just remove the HD and check the connector or should I do some kind of procedure before?